# I want to read xml using xpath and get the count of parent in java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I want to read the xml using xpath java, read the parent node and get the count of that, after that i have to use the parent node and get the child nodes count
parent node is -

Please some one help me out this.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<ab_rsp status="ok">


-<itm title="United States" guid="04570A9A-6066-11E2-BB55-FF519035903F" type="country">


-<itm title="Arizona" guid="A83274AC-901A-11DF-A622-0C319DFF4B22" type="authority">


-<itm title="Academic Standards" guid="9935C580-C0DA-11DA-80AA-DCC515614119" type="document">


-<itm title="Technology" guid="E3E0AD06-FC32-11D9-8407-9AE6FB2C8371" type="subject">

<meta name="year">2000</meta>


-<itm title="Readiness (Kindergarten)" guid="001DCFCC-2A74-11D8-A1A9-EB97E8AED672" type="grade">

<meta name="grade" lo="K" hi="K"/>


-<itm guid="929A5FA4-29E4-11D8-9FDA-DEE83CF00340" type="standard">

<meta name="num">1T-R</meta>

<meta name="descr">Fundamental Operations and Concepts</meta>


-<itm guid="92A019DA-29E4-11D8-94F3-918A2ADD362B" type="standard">

<meta name="num">1T-R1</meta>

<meta name="descr">Communicate about basic technology components using developmentally appropriate and accurate terminology</meta>


-<itm guid="92A2E14C-29E4-11D8-9510-E88CF3390259" type="standard">

<meta name="num">1T-R1.PO 1</meta>

<meta name="descr">Use basic vocabulary related to the use of technology (e.g., mouse, keyboard, monitor, toolbar, menu, window, folder, icon, spreadsheet, word processor, cassette player, CD player versus DVD versus video tape, video camera)</meta>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92A5BFAC-29E4-11D8-B459-9A03B60B3918" type="standard">

<meta name="num">1T-R1.PO 2</meta>

<meta name="descr">Identify the components of a computer (e.g., mouse, keyboard, monitor, CPU, printer)</meta>

</itm>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92A89C36-29E4-11D8-80CB-9286DFCA4E08" type="standard">

<meta name="num">1T-R2</meta>

<meta name="descr">Use input devices and output devices successfully to operate computers, VCRs, audiotapes, and other technologies</meta>


-<itm guid="92AB7870-29E4-11D8-81C8-FBD15B9102AD" type="standard">

<meta name="num">1T-R2.PO 1</meta>

<meta name="descr">Demonstrate start up and shut down procedures of basic technology components (e.g., computers, tape recorders, cassette players, VCRs)</meta>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92AE5900-29E4-11D8-BADC-9BE3FF051872" type="standard">

<meta name="num">1T-R2.PO 2</meta>

<meta name="descr">Use devices to complete a task (e.g., mouse, keyboard, printer, remote control, microphone)</meta>

</itm>

</itm>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92B11F50-29E4-11D8-8666-D70924C27789" type="standard">

<meta name="num">2T-R</meta>

<meta name="descr">Social, Ethical and Human Issues</meta>


-<itm guid="92B9B4EE-29E4-11D8-8819-C3322442EC44" type="standard">

<meta name="num">2T-R1</meta>

<meta name="descr">Work cooperatively and collaboratively when using technology in the classroom</meta>


-<itm guid="92BCA960-29E4-11D8-A217-F8D5963215AE" type="standard">

<meta name="num">2T-R1.PO 1</meta>

<meta name="descr">Demonstrate respect for other students while using technology (e.g., take turns, share resources)</meta>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92BF7104-29E4-11D8-9926-9EF61CBC1B4F" type="standard">

<meta name="num">2T-R1.PO 2</meta>

<meta name="descr">Demonstrate appropriate behavior (e.g., use only your documents and folders)</meta>

</itm>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92C24E38-29E4-11D8-91F7-D0E3C7F2A956" type="standard">

<meta name="num">2T-R2</meta>

<meta name="descr">Practice responsible use of technological devices</meta>


-<itm guid="92C52BD0-29E4-11D8-9F50-8FC6DBAC1404" type="standard">

<meta name="num">2T-R2.PO 1</meta>

<meta name="descr">Operate equipment to ensure equipment is unharmed (e.g., do not bang on keys; no food or objects near equipment; care for disks and CD-ROM; use proper shut down procedures)</meta>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92C8072E-29E4-11D8-A2CE-8EBA3106B953" type="standard">

<meta name="num">2T-R2.PO 2</meta>

<meta name="descr">Recognize that damaging school equipment is destroying public property</meta>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92CAE4DA-29E4-11D8-8F74-80A2BA5F84A1" type="standard">

<meta name="num">2T-R2.PO 3</meta>

<meta name="descr">Recognize that changing someone’s work without permission is unacceptable</meta>

</itm>

</itm>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92EA3CCC-29E4-11D8-A09B-DF874AC58F3F" type="standard">

<meta name="num">3T-R</meta>

<meta name="descr">Technology Productivity Tools</meta>


-<itm guid="92CDC29A-29E4-11D8-9E76-C7CA8D85B9B7" type="standard">

<meta name="num">3T-R1</meta>

<meta name="descr">Use technology drawing tools for communicating and illustrating</meta>


-<itm guid="92D92248-29E4-11D8-B2AD-9AD0B7A1AB7B" type="standard">

<meta name="num">3T-R1.PO 1</meta>

<meta name="descr">Using a drawing program, create a picture story with support from teacher, family members or student partners</meta>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92D644BA-29E4-11D8-8BF2-D14836F4F6A1" type="standard">

<meta name="num">3T-R1.PO 2</meta>

<meta name="descr">Using a drawing program, add name and letters to illustrations</meta>

</itm>

</itm>

</itm>

</itm>

</itm>

</itm>

</itm>

</itm>

</ab_rsp>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Parent node is -<itm title="Readiness (Kindergarten)" guid="001DCFCC-2A74-11D8-A1A9-EB97E8AED672" type="grade">

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

you need to read xpath doc - there are plenty of methods

you can use this to get your nodes

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression="//itm";

NodeList nodes  = (NodeList)  xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

this to get their parents

```
nodep = node.getParentNode();
```

for one child

```
 the_node.getFirstChild();
```

this to get their children (if you have an element)

```
if  (the_node instanceof Element)
{
  Element the_element=(Element) the_node;

  NodeList nodes  = the_element.getChildNodes();
```

count is direct

```
nodes.getLength()
```

to iterate, it is direct too

```
for(int i=0; i<nodes.getLength(); i++)
{
 Node the_node = nodes.item(i);
```

hope this helps